# Nginx Custom errors not displaying

Tags: nginx, config

I am having some problems with my Nginx config on RHEL, I am trying to configure custom error pages, this is a bit of my config:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;

    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/^/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/^/ssl.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;  


    server_name   ~^(www\.)?(?P<domain>.+)$;
    root   /www/$domain;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/my_domain;
    location ~ ^/(403|404|405|50x).html {
        root /www/^/error;
    }


    location ~ .php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /www/$domain$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Any way I have read everything and I'm not sure what to do to fix it :( and before anyone asks... yes I have restarted nginx!

Comment: Where is your `error_page` directive?

Comment: Also, you have weird path in `root` directive for error pages.